# Is importing a truetype font for perl module possible?

Tags: linux, perl, pdf, truetype

After a great deal of toiling I have managed to hack up a perl script that use [PDF::Create](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Create) to create pdf labels for a label printer. The script now works perfectly to suit my needs but the choices of fonts are limited. I have installed a true type font with gnome-font-viewer (I am using Debian Stretch).

According to the [docs for PDF::Create](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Create#font(%params)): A postscript named "BaseFont" (Courier, Courier-Bold, Courier-BoldOblique, Courier-Oblique, Helvetica, Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica-BoldOblique, Helvetica-Oblique, Times-Roman, Times-Bold, Times-Italic, Times-BoldItalic or Symbol) can be used to create the pdf.

How can I add my newly installed true type font to this list of Postscript basefonts so that I can use it to create a PDF? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 4):

There is an old and unresolved [ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=64238) requesting that feature on that module, so I suspect for PDF::Create, the answer is no, you can't use TTF fonts (I'd be happy to be proven wrong on that point).

Other Perl modules *can* use True Type and Open Type fonts. [PDF::API2](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2) does support them.  I'll confess, I found that module's API to be somewhat intimidating.

Another module I have used extensively is [PDF::Reuse](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Reuse) which can be used to create PDFs from scratch, or by combining existing pages as templates and overlaying text and other elements.  PDF::Reuse also supports the use of True Type fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Grant. I rewrote my script using PDF::API2. Works great.